# Use Tags of Stack in CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am quite new at designing CloudFormation Template, is it possible to use stack tags value defined just before launching the stack creation inside the template?

For example :

```
"EC2I2C2EJ": {
   "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
      "Properties": {
      "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3a",
      "ImageId": "ami-0152e5e7567b014fc",
      "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "Type" }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: And example of what you are trying to achieve will help you get better, do look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to create a better example

Comment: Is it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can apply tags to the Cloudformation stack without having to manually fill them in through the Create Stack Wizard however this needs to be done over the CLI or using Boto3/CreateStack API call. Tags will automatically be added to your Cloudformation stack via this method and these tags will also - where appropriate - propagate onto resources you launch, i.e. the EC2 instance you are creating.

You can add tags inside the Cloudformation template like so for specific resources:

```
"EC2I2C2EJ": {
  "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
  "Properties": {
  "AvailabilityZone": "eu-west-3a",
  "ImageId": "ami-0152e5e7567b014fc",
  "InstanceType": { "Ref" : "Type" },
  "Tags" : [
        {
            "Key" : "Tag1",
            "Value" : "Test"
        },
   ]
 }
}
```